# rename tabs in ubuntu 18.04 terminal

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome-terminal, tabs

Is there a way to change the name of individual tabs in the default gnome terminal? ie one tab is "tab1", the next tab is "another_tab"

To be clear, I don't want to change the prompt, just the name of each tab. I thought of going with tmux but wanted to see if I can get away with something simpler since renaming is really all I need.

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? If you tack hardly related questions onto existing questions you broaden their scope which makes them harder to answer. On top of that it likely invalidates existing answers. I took the liberty to revert the edit that adds the follow-up question. Thanks.